# Rails 4, Calling destroy method on my User model: RuntimeError at /users/ Can't modify frozen hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hash, solr, destroy

I have a member model and a user model.

member.rb

```
 has_one :user, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
```

user.rb

```
 belongs_to :member, dependent: :destroy
```

I have a destroy method in the user......

```
def destroy
 session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
 if current_user.admin?
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(session.delete(:return_to))}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(session.delete(:return_to))}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

end

I am also sing sunspot:solr in my app.

When I try to delete the user via the destroy method my console dumps this

```
SOLR Request (10.6ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (11.6ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (13.6ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (12.3ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (13.1ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (14.8ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (14.4ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (16.2ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
```

and keeps going. Then eventually stops with

```
  RuntimeError at /users/simon-walshe
  Can't modify frozen hash
```

What is happening. I am guessing there is an issue with the relationships or something but i can't figure it out....

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an object , the attributes will be freezed by rails. read more about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete)

So what you can do is, before deleting/destroying you can check if the object is already destroyed.

something like

```
user.destroy unless user.destroyed?
```